# Ruby Script API That Requires a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rubygems, crm

I have spent almost 8 hours on this and I know it's an easy fix.

I want to use this [repository](https://github.com/basecrm/basecrm) of the basecrm gem.

The problem: I don't know how to require/include the gem, neither locally as a cloned copy or as a regular "require gem_name" to find [Leads](https://github.com/basecrm/basecrm/wiki/Leads)

- Ive download and put the gem files in /Users/username/Sites/basecrm/ 
  and added the line below to my gem file.

`gem 'basecrm', :git => 'git://github.com/basecrm/basecrm.git'`

- I ran "Bundle Install"
- According to the Readme.md it says to call

  `require 'basecrm'`

> ```
> ⌘ ~/Sites/basecrm/   irb
> irb(main):001:0     require 'basecrm'
> LoadError: cannot load such file -- basecrm
> from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
> from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
> from (irb):1
> from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
> irb(main):002:0session = BaseCrm::Session.new
> NameError: uninitialized constant BaseCrm
> from (irb):2
> from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
> ```

Any help is really appreciated. I am ready to tear my hair out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Gemfile you should run irb with bundler e.g. `bundle exec irb` and then require your gem `require "basecrm"`